# Volley & AsyncTask : Response orrder

Tags: android, android-asynctask, synchronization, android-volley

**Context** : networking(http request and response).

My question has two parts - one about `volley` and one about `AsyncTask`.

I'm learning to implement `httpConnection` using `volley` and `AsyncTask`, so please bear with me.

My question is, in **what order the callbacks are called**, after getting response from network? (In the case of `volley` and `AsyncTask`)

Are callbacks executed sequentially?

Consider this scenario,

I have 2 `AsyncTask`s. After getting response form network at same time, in what order callback will be called in `postExecute()`? Will both callbacks to UI thread will occur simultaneously as 2 `Asynctask`s are in seperate threads? or will they be executed sequentially?

I have read these SO posts,

[can-i-do-a-synchronous-request-with-volley](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16904741/can-i-do-a-synchronous-request-with-volley)

[multiple-asynctasks-onpostexecute-order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17489551/multiple-asynctasks-onpostexecute-order)

[running-multiple-asynctasks-at-the-same-time-not-possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068984/running-multiple-asynctasks-at-the-same-time-not-possible)

[how-to-manage-multiple-async-tasks-efficiently-in-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9221343/how-to-manage-multiple-async-tasks-efficiently-in-android)

[how-to-synchronize-two-async-task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18914014/how-to-synchronize-two-async-task)

**Thanks**

**Edit** :
Consider this code of `AsyncTask` implementation,

```
public class AsyncTaskImplementation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private final interface appAsyncTaskInterface;
 
    public interface responseInterface {
        void onSuccessHttpResponse(String resultJsonObject);
        void onFailedHttpResponse(String failedMessage);
    }

    public AsyncTaskImplementation(){
        //initialise
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        //executeHttpRequest and return
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        //pre execute stuff like connection checking
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (result != null&& !result.equals("")) {
            responseInterface.onSuccessResponse(result);
        } else {
            responseInterface.onFailedinterface("failed");
        }
    }
}
```

**Question wrt to above code** :

Consider two `AsyncTaskImplementation` objects, `A` and `B` created in a UI thread.

Now `A` and `B` will execute a http request (assume the code is implemented).

After that they will return response through interface `responseInterface`.

So my question is regarding this. Will `A` and `B` simultaneously invoke callback methods in UI thread through `responseInterface`?

Should I use `synchronized` to make sure that callbacks are synchronized? Or `AsyncTask` ensures that callbacks are invoked sequentially?

Comment: do you want to know from which request you got the response ?

Comment: Nope. I want to know the order in which callbacks are called?Sequential or parallel?

Comment: Sequential if you are sending request in async

Comment: So callbacks to UI thread are in sequential even if they are from different  `AsycTask`?

Comment: Well you need to implement interfaces for this because there might be the case that one service return you exception where as second gives you result

Comment: I wonder where you are talking about. There are no callbacks in AsyncTask to begin with.